# Excel - extract hours/minutes from time more than 24 hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, time, date-time

The displayed value in A1 is **177:53:00**

The custom format is **[h]:mm:ss**

The value when I click A1 is **1900-01-07  9:53:00 AM**

I need to extract the hours (177) from the cell to another cell

Couldn't find a formula to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As correctly pointed out by Akina, due to the inaccuracies inherent in the floating point numbers that Excel uses to a store serial date value, the `INT()` function will not work correctly to extract the hours after multiplying it by `24`.

However, the function can be used to extract the number of days, and combined with the `HOUR()` function which *does* correctly extract the number of hours from the fractional part of the serial date value, we get the following formula:

```dart
=HOUR(A1)+INT(A1)*24
```

As explained by Aganju, the integer part of a serial date value represents days, so multiplying it by `24` will give the number of hours of the serial date value due to the whole days. Adding in the number of hours due to the partial day gives us the total number of hours.

Comment: @fixer1234 *I'm not seeing why Aganju's simple solution would be inaccurate.* See my first comment to my answer.

Comment: @Akina and robinCTS, the time functions and time formatting round seconds to integer values. If you are doing time math and want to extract the individual time components, that rounding will produce the wrong answer. In real life, you don't get another hour until a full 3600 seconds have passed. Until then, you have minutes, seconds, milliseconds, etc. that total less than an hour. The Excel functions round up to the next hour when you are less than half a second short of the next hour. That's the wrong answer.

Comment: BTW, the time functions can't be more accurate than the floating point values because that's what they use for calculation.  The floating point inaccuracy is 100,000 times more accurate than the time functions, which introduce a 1/2 second error.

Comment: @fixer1234 You know, when I wrote that bit stating the floating point inaccuracy was the issue, something at the back of my mind was nagging at me about it. I brushed it aside, but made a mental note to investigate further later (－‸ლ) Should have listened. You are absolutely right - it's at least five orders of magnitude away from being the possible cause! Thanks for bringing the ½ second issue to my attention. I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use =INT(A1*24).

Excel stores dates and times internally in *days*. Multiplying by 24 gives you hours, and INT cuts off the minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"),FIND(":",TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"))-1)
```

Comment: Can you explain the above? :)

Comment: That's a big detour - just use `=INT(A1*24)`. Excelstores dates and times internally in days. Multiplying by 24 gives you hours, and INT removes the minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Aganju No, your solution may give wrong result. For example, check both formula with `A1=1.041661`.

Comment: @Akina, your formula produced #Value error , just check it!

Comment: @Aganju, Yes your formula is getting 177, post it as answer !

Comment: @RajeshS What type and value you place into A1 cell? check **IT**. And what locale you use? check data format string, it is to be local...

Comment: Exactly as shown by OP .

Comment: @RajeshS This formula gives correct result on my workstation after editing data format string to the national one. Do the same.

Comment: @RajeshS The formula was checked on GoogleSpreadsheet. See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nyxobV_6GlYfw_UG18ZvR5i89bk1fE_X-E2BOJ9NyqY/edit?usp=sharing - the result is correct. Check yourself.

Comment: @RajeshS, I also tested the formula on LO Calc and it works.  If you're getting an error, I suspect your value is being treated as text (perhaps a locale issue).

Comment: @fixer1234, It may possible the value I've entered is exactly as shown by OP & the format is Date Customize to accommodate Date & Time both & my regional setting for regional Language is `US`, keyboard format is also `US`, default date is `MM/DD/YYYY` & `(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delh` is time Zone.

Comment: @RajeshS *the value I've entered is exactly as shown by OP* Enter the value `7.4118` and then format it as elapsed time (`[h]:mm:ss`).

Comment: @RajeshS, it must all be in the wrist action.  :-)  Strange that it doesn't work on your computer.  Akina, I tried your A1=1.041661 example (Aganju challenge).  Interesting.  To me, it looks like the Excel functions and formatting algorithms are in error.  They are rounding up when the difference is small.  If the goal is to extract time units, rounding will give the wrong answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 *it looks like the Excel functions and formatting algorithms are in error* No. The formula asks to handle the value as a number - and Excel processes it as a number, with common float value inaccuracy. It's the reason I use functions which processes the initial value as a time one - with accuracy. Implicit casting is evil.

Comment: Your formula rounds up and produces the wrong answer for 1.041661.  The result should be 24 hours + change.  It doesn't become 25 hours until a time value of 1.0416666667.  It's not because of floating point inaccuracy because the difference is much larger than that.  It's because Excel is rounding to the nearest second.  You can't rely on those time functions or time formatting for time math that needs to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Returned to it after some time. Following the answer of @Akina, my final formula is

=INT(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"),FIND(":",TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"))-1)) + (INT(MID(TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"),FIND(":",TEXT(A1,"[h]:mm:ss"))+1,2))/60)

1900-01-07 9:53:00 AM

Which is displayed as

177:53:00

is returned as

177.88

Comment: This is a very convoluted way to get to the wrong answer (it will be wrong when you are close to the next hour but not quite there).  See the discussion in the comments.  The time functions and time formatting round up, which gives an incorrect time when it is close by a fraction of a second.  If you want the time to be accurate, you need a variant of Aganju's answer (if you want fractional hours, you would need to adjust the formula).